# Build Module failed when using TSLint with webpack

Tags: webpack, tslint

I am trying to run TSLint on my project and it is currently failing when trying to build with webpack. I have created a simple repro of my project with the following structure:

```
\tslint-issue  
    |-\src
    |   |-Base.ts
    |   |-Derived.ts
    |   |-index.tsx
    |-babel.rc
    |-index.html
    |-package.json
    |-tsconfig.json
    |-webpack.config.json
```

Base and Derived are pretty simple class definitions. But when I run

```
webpack
```

I get the following message:

```
    ERROR in ./src/Derived.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: this.computeFullOptions is not a function
    at Object.Linter (c:\Code\tslint-issue\node_modules\tslint\lib\tslint.js:15:29)
 @ ./src/index.tsx 2:16-36
```

When I remove the following section from my *webpack.config.json*

```
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'tslint'
            },
```

It works fine. If more info is required I can provide any piece of the project necessary. The index.tsx imports the `Derived` class in `Derived.ts` file has the following contents:

```
import { Derived } from "./Derived";

var d = new Derived(25);
console.log(d.AbsMethod());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing **tslint-loader**.

`npm install --save-dev tslint-loader` should do the trick.

Comment: Totally fixed it! Thanks so much. It was not obvious from the error what was happening.I tried to edit you comment to remove the dash (-) after npm but it is not sufficient of a edit to do. Good eye, not that I see I did not even include the package.json.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo! I've fixed it, and agree that the error is a bit misleading. I found your question after Googling the same red herring error message and eventually figured it out.